# A general formula for the parametrisation of the tangent space (in $\Bbb{R}^n$)

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametrization, tangent-spaces

I couldn't find a sufficiently general formula for the tangent plane of a parametric surface, so I derived one. The formula I came up with also defines the tangent line of a parametric curve in $n$-dimensions, the tangent plane to an explicitly defined surface, and the tangent plane to a parametric surface in $n$-dimensions:

> Let $\mathbf{f}:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n:m<n$ be a parametrisation of an
>   $m$-dimensional geometric object (possibly but not necessarily a
>   manifold, algebraic variety, etc.) in Euclidean $n$-space. The parametrisation of the tangent
>   space $T_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{f}:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ at a point
>   $\mathbf{u}\in\Bbb{R}^m$ is given by...
>
> $$T_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{J}_\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u})$$
>
> ...where $\mathbf{J}_\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u})$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{f}$ evaluated at $\mathbf{u}$.

The resulting parametrisation preserves information about local scaling and orientation within the coordinate system. This is particularly noticeable when considering changes to the basis vectors$^*$ of the tangent space between two points $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{u}'$ along a curve, as shown below (I apologise for the quality, upload limits and all that)...
[image]
[image]

**Edit**

Originally I had written this formula as...

$$T_\mathbf{u}f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_i\left(\nabla f_i(\mathbf{u})\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})+f_i(\mathbf{u})\right)\mathbf{e}^i$$

After Ted Shifrin's comment I realise that this is easier expressed in terms of the Jacobian. Shortly after editing this question, I found this on the Wikipedia article about the Jacobian...

$${\displaystyle \mathbf {f} (\mathbf {x} )-\mathbf {f} (\mathbf {p} )=\mathbf {J} _{\mathbf {f} }(\mathbf {p} )(\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {p})+o(\|\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {p} \|)\quad ({\text{as }}\mathbf {x} \to \mathbf {p} )}$$

...which is very close to my formula. The fact that the Jacobian is the closest linear approximation of vector-valued function explains why $T_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{f}$ is a close linear approximation of $\mathbf{f}$ near $\mathbf{u}$, but does not explain why this gives the tangent space whenever $m<n$.

Intuitively, this seems like a generalisation of Taylor's theorem to vector-valued functions. Indeed, the equation of the tangent line is given by the Taylor polynomial of degree $1$...

$$y=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$$

I'm not quite sure how to get from here to my formula though, or how to show that $T_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{f}$ is the tangent space of $\mathbf{f}$ for all [differentiable] $f:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I haven't read all this, but presumably what you're writing down in a long-winded fashion is just the image of the derivative mapping $D_{\mathbf u}f$, translated so that it passes through the point $\mathbf x = f(\mathbf u)$. In higher math, we usually refer to the tangent space as a subspace, rather than an affine subspace, so we don't translate off the origin.

Comment: What do you mean by "the derivative $D_\mathbf{u}f$"?

Comment: I mean the derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf u$ (I was trying to follow your notation), which is the $n\times m$ matrix of partial derivatives of components of $f$. (See, for example, my lectures on YouTube, linked in my profile.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Isn't that just the Jacobian evaluated at $\mathbf{u}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is all classic stuff.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. I've made some edits to the question. The parametrisation given is not generally equivalent to the image of the Jacobian under translation, but is most closely the "Taylor polynomial" of degree $1$. While this certainly *is* classic stuff, I can't seem to find any reference to this being used to find the tangent space (aside from the single-variable example, where the Jacobian is just the derivative). I'm not even sure how to prove that $T_\mathbf{u}$ *is* the tangent space in the general case.